# Add an array object in an array or add new index in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an object in javascript file

```
myArray:{
  id:'',
  arr1:[],
  arr2:[]
}
```

I need to add new object in arr1. it should be like this..

```
myArray:{
  id:'',
  arr1:{
   index1:'',
   index2:''
  },
  arr2:{
   index1:'',
   index2:''
  }
} // code formatting
```

Yes, that should be the structure. Ive tried to use array.push however didnt work.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `myArray` is object not array

Comment: Did you use namespacing while pushing in the array? myArray.arr1.push()?

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: Hi Vigneswaran Marimuthu, im sorry . ill update my question later..

Comment: $scope.array2={
           val1: 'name1',
           val2: 'name2'
     }

I need to add array2 in arr1..

Ive tried this..

     for (var key in child)
     {
        $scope.myArray.arr1.push(child[key].val1)
     }

Answer (score 1):

as Vigneswaran mention its object not array
you can directly do that

```
myArray.arr1={index1:'',index2:''};
```

Comment: $scope.array2={ name:'san-san', add:'usa' }

I want to make the 'san-san' as one of the index in arr1.. how would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

myArray is not an array, it is an Object.
If I understand correctly, you can get what you want by this..

```
var myArray = {
              id:'',
              arr1:{},
              arr2:{}
            };  
console.log(myArray);           
myArray.arr1 = { index1:'', index2:''};
myArray.arr2 = { index1:'', index2:''};
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments on this one.
`myArray` is an object. In order to access a property, you have to use `myArray.property`.
`arr1` and `arr2` are properties of `myArray`, so use `myArray.arr1.push(thing)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = {
  id:'',
  arr1:[],
  arr2:[]
};
alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
delete myArray['arr1'];
delete myArray['arr2'];
myArray['arr1'] ={
   index1:'',
   index2:''
  };
myArray['arr2'] = {
   index1:'',
   index2:''
  };
alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p7dpgsv5/)**

Comment: Hi ozil, thanks for the demo however the index to be added is dynamic.. 
   sampArr=[name:'san-san',add:'usa']
I need to add 'san-san' as the index.. how will i do this?

Comment: @ san-san here `sampArr` is `an array` and in you post `myArray` is an `object`. object does not have index